# How long do bundles get persisted by SyncManager?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have an application with a `SyncAdapter`. Additionally to the normal synchronization I trigger a `USER_READ` event with which I just pass a `Bundle` to the adapter without persisting it:

```
Bundle settingsBundle = new Bundle();
settingsBundle.putString(SyncAdapter.USER_READ, uid);
ContentResolver.requestSync(account, authority, settingsBundle);
```

This will correctly call my synchronization routine sometime in the future. Every `uid` set in the `Bundle` will trigger its own run and everything gets synced as expected.

If now the connection is bad, or the request times out, then I set a soft error:

```
syncResult.stats.numIoExceptions += 1;
```

which will cause the request to be repeated later. This also works just fine.

---

*How long do these SyncRequests / Bundles get persisted?*

The documentation states, that encountering a soft error will cause an exponentional backoff and that the sync will be run some time later.

- Will it be canceled at some point? After multiple soft errors?
- Will it be enqueued again after a reboot of the device?

Given the connection is bad and the synchronization fails multiple times with soft errors: I would like to know if just enqueuing a sync request is enough, or if I have to provide some sort of persistence myself to ensure requests being sent at some point.

Comment: It depends on your requirement that it will be When the system sends out a network message , At regular intervals , On demand like  after a reboot of the device read http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html

Comment: @WaqasAhmed Thank you, yes. I know the documentation. I just wonder about the specifics how long those requests will persist, especially if I don't just use *full sync* but need the data from the bundles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to dig in Android runtime source a little to find an answer to your question. Let's start from the first part of the question.

> Will it [sync] be canceled at some point? After multiple soft errors?

And the answer is probably no, until one of the following conditions is met:

- sync is cancelled
- you ask `SyncManager` not to reschedule sync by starting `SyncAdapter` with `ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_DO_NOT_RETRY`
- you set `SyncResult.tooManyRetries` to `true` and sync isn't upload-only
- you set `SyncResult.tooManyDeletions` to `true`, don't set `SyncStats.numInserts` or `SyncStats.numUpdates` to non-null values, and sync isn't upload-only
- sync has no soft errors but has some hard errors, and it's not upload-only
- sync runs for more than 30 minutes
- sync doesn't use network for more than 1 minute

So multiple soft errors don't cancel sync and here's why.

Handling all sync events starts in [`SyncManager.SyncHandler.handleMessage()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-6.0.1_r16/services/core/java/com/android/server/content/SyncManager.java#L2201) method and continues in [`SyncManager.runSyncFinishedOrCanceledH()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-6.0.1_r16/services/core/java/com/android/server/content/SyncManager.java#L3031) method. The first argument of `runSyncFinishedOrCanceledH()` is `SyncResult`, which can be `null`. It's not `null` either when sync is finished or when `SyncAdapter` service is disconnected, which is a soft error. And it's `null` when sync is cancelled, expired (runs more than 30 minutes), not using network for more than 1 minute, and in another case I don't fully understand.

In case `SyncResult` is not `null` and sync finished with errors, `SyncManager` tries to reschedule sync by calling [`maybeRescheduleSync()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-6.0.1_r16/services/core/java/com/android/server/content/SyncManager.java#L3069). This methods checks some flags and sync results, like `ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_DO_NOT_RETRY` and `SyncResult.tooManyRetries` do decide if it needs to reschedule sync. And after `SyncManager` checks that sync finished with a soft error [`syncResult.hasSoftError()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-6.0.1_r16/services/core/java/com/android/server/content/SyncManager.java#L1210) it reschedules sync without any additional checks.

And now the second part of the question.

> Will it [sync] be enqueued again after a reboot of the device?

Yes, it will. When `SystemServer` initializes, it creates [`ContentService`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-6.0.1_r16/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java#L474) and then calls its [`systemReady()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-6.0.1_r16/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java#L759) method, which in its turn creates [`SyncManager`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-6.0.1_r16/services/core/java/com/android/server/content/ContentService.java#L173). `SyncManager` in its constructor creates [`SyncStorageEngine`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-6.0.1_r16/services/core/java/com/android/server/content/SyncManager.java#L428), which [reads all pending operations](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-6.0.1_r16/services/core/java/com/android/server/content/SyncStorageEngine.java#L528) in its constructor [including extra bundles](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-6.0.1_r16/services/core/java/com/android/server/content/SyncStorageEngine.java#L2540). That's why a set of types allowed in sync bundles is very limited. And when user is starting all pending operations are added to `SynqQueue` by calling [`SyncQueue.addPendingOperations()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-6.0.1_r16/services/core/java/com/android/server/content/SyncManager.java#L1233).

This answer is the result of my analysis of Android code so I cannot guarantee it's 100% correct. But you can use this information as a starting point for your own research.

Comment: This was the kind of answer I was looking for, thank you!